# Drag'n'Drop playlist - Spotify

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

Is it possible to get playlist uri, with a drag and drop (in spotify)?

I've made the drag and drop function, but only the drag work:

```
function drag(){
    console.log("drag");
}
function drop(){
    console.log("drop");
}
var dropZone = document.getElementById("drop");
dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", drag, false);
dropZone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
```

And have included this in my maninest (If it isnt right, please tell me):

```
"AcceptedLinkTypes": [
    "playlist"
]
```

Comment: typo in yourcode : 
dropZone.addEventListener("drop", drag, false); should be dropZone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);. what doesnt work ?

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work either D:

Comment: Nobody knows this? @camus the comment above, was for you (Just forgot to include you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a great tutorial, on how to do this :D

https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink

Its almost explains everything! :D

So if anyone is having a problem with their app, or just want to learn how to make one.
You should really check this out.. :D

Comment: How did you finally solve it? I'm getting the same error, the dragover event is triggered but not the drop event.

Comment: @mabounassif Be sure to [handle to drops like this](https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink/blob/master/js/social.js#L9-35), and you need this in your [manifest](https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink/blob/master/manifest.json#L5-11)

Comment: Awesome the problem really was that we needed to prevent the default  behaviour of the event....

Comment: @mabounassif It was the same for me... :D